# Ran Microsoft Security Essential after malware attack, now Windows won't open

Tags: windows-xp, ms-security-essentials

After I was hit by malware (from an email I opened) I downloaded Microsoft Security Essentials. Scanned and and cleared my computer. I shut down for a restart but now Windows won't launch.

It gets to a loading screen but shuts down before the login screen. I've tried running in Safe Mode etc. and it still won't launch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to launch again, but press <kd>F8</kbd> at start and choose `Disable Restart on System Failure` and say what is wrong.

Comment: @wil Amen, this would be quite helpful.

Comment: does it try to load the desktop then reboot? We need more info on exactly what it does when windows tries to load.